# Executable shell file in Windows

Tags: python, bash, exe, samba

I have a executable file working in Ubuntu that runs a script in Python and works fine. I have also a shared directory with Samba server. The idea is that everyone (even Windows users) can execute this executable file located in this shared folder to run the script located in my computer.

But, how can I make an executable file that runs the python script of MY computer from both Linux and Windows remote users?

Comment: What is the interpreter that this script requires? bash?

Comment: Yes. And within the script in bash I call to the python script: `python my_script.py`.

Comment: So, if you expect a Windows user to invoke this, they will have to have both bash and python installed. You may need to write a Windows .bat file for your Windows users. And you say the python script is NOT located in the shared dir? How do you think remote user's will be able to run it?

Comment: The python script is in the same shared dir than the bash script. But what I want is that a Windows user can click on the executable file (the bash script) and then my Ubuntu PC starts the execution.

Comment: Then the bash script will have to do: `ssh user@your_machine python path/to/script.py`

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to install [Cygwin](http://cygwin.org/), a UNIX/Linux emulation package for Windows. Note that you will need to install Python on all the computers on which your program shall run.

Otherwise you could use some form of remote execution, so that Windows users actually run your program on the Ubuntu computer.

Comment: Do I need to install Python in a Windows PC to run remotely the script in my Ubuntu PC?

Comment: No, if you run it remotely you only need something like PuTTY

Comment: I was thinking in something like PuTTY. Can I make a executable that sends a instruction from Windows to Linux through PuTTY to start the execution of the script? That would be awesome.

Comment: This blog page shows how: http://pythianpang.wordpress.com/2009/05/14/let-putty-run-command-in-remote-server/

Answer (score 0):

As you've said, this executable file would need to be something that runs on both Linux and Windows. That will exclude binary files, such as compiled C files.

What you are left with would be an executable script, which could be

- Bash
- Ruby
- Python
- PHP
- Perl

If need be the script could simply be a bootstrapper that loads the appropriate binary executable depending on the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Install Python for Windows http://www.python.org/download/

Then the Python program should be executable. But the `cmd.exe` would simply close after the result are printed.

I would make a batch file with the following (the `/k` simply keeps the screen open after it finishes)

```
C:\Windows\System32\CMD.EXE /k "foo.py"
```

Assuming `foo.py` is your Python program. And save the batch file.

Then you should be able to run the batch file and giving the output of your Python script